# Libgdx is Character on Screen

Tags: camera

Inside an entity class:

```
public boolean onScreen(Camera camera){
    if(position.x + getWidth() > camera.position.x
            && position.x < camera.position.x + camera.viewportWidth
            && position.y < camera.position.y + camera.viewportHeight
            && position.y + getHeight() > camera.position.y){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function returns false even when the entity is on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not use the Camera.Frustum? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera

Also try switching your > and <. Im not sure what camera.position is, whether its the bottom left or center, but that may be your problem

Comment: The reason was that camera.position was center. Thanks!